# Fetch Count of Specific Relation to a Node in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, neo4jclient

I have a scenario in Neo4J where a "User" Node Relates to a Node "Post" with relation Name as "WRITES".Now the "Post" node can receive relation named "LIKES" from other Nodes(User).Now I want to fetch the data of the post written by the User mentioned in where Clause and it's corresponding likes count. I have written the below query but it is not working.

```
MATCH (user:User)-[WRITES]-(myp:Post)<-[l:LIKES]-()
where user ="xyz"
RETURN myp,count(l) as count
```

I intend to receive the Post which was added by the specific User and the Count of Likes and later convert it into C#. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query isn't valid in a couple of ways.

First, you're comparing a whole User node to the string "xyz" in your `WHERE` clause - you instead should be querying on the properties of your matched User nodes.

Second, you're missing a colon before `WRITES` that means you're actually matching *any* relationship type and giving it the variable name `WRITES` in the rest of the query. You instead probably want the following:

For example, let's say that User nodes have a 'username' property:

```
MATCH (user:User)-[:WRITES]-(myp:Post)<-[l:LIKES]-()
WHERE user.username = "xyz"
RETURN myp, count(l) as count
```

Also, unless the `WRITES` relationship is genuinely directionless (i.e. that Post nodes can somehow write Users), you should probably include an arrow in that relationship to limit the search space a bit:

```
MATCH (user:User)-[:WRITES]->(myp:Post)<-[l:LIKES]-()
WHERE user.username = "xyz"
RETURN myp, count(l) as count
```

If you want to return posts even if they've received no likes, we need to remove the `LIKES` relationship from the pattern and calculate the number of likes slightly differently:

```
MATCH (user: User)-[:WRITES]->(myp:Post)
WHERE user.username = "xyz"
RETURN myp, size((myp)<-[:LIKES]-()) as count
```

Comment: Thanks for correcting the query. However when I am executing the last mentioned query it returns 0 records if there are no likes to the post. Is there any way where I can fetch the post detail and the like count as 0 if no likes are received to the post.

Comment: Can you please help by providing c# code for the last added query. I am finding it difficult to convert into c# with the return statement.

Comment: Not really, that's just doing the work for you rather than answering a question - I suggest you look at [the documentation](https://neo4j.com/developer/dotnet/) for the .NET libraries. I've found the [community library](https://github.com/Readify/Neo4jClient) to be slightly easier to use if you've got a background in Linq. Give that a go and raise specific questions after you've tried something, I suggest.